How to make a function wait for an async operation before executing further code?
I have an async function my_func that performs two operations: f and g. The f operation sends data over a WebSocket and doesn't return anything. The g operation performs some computations and returns a value.
async def my_func(self, a: str, b: str) -> str:
    await f(a, b) # sends data on websocket
    out = g(a, b)
    return out

The problem is that g executes immediately after f is called, without waiting for the WebSocket operation to complete. I need g to execute only after f has finished sending the data over the WebSocket.
How can I modify this code to make g wait for the async operation f to complete before executing?
Please note that f doesn't return anything, so I can't use the standard await on its return value.

await already ensures that f finishes before continuing.  On the other hand, if f itself calls another function without waiting for it to finish, there's not much you can do outside of modifying f.

await does not change the flow of functions; it just gives up time for other code to run while it's waiting for an answer.
